# How to streamline multiple coordinate poly line entries in MKMapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, polyline, poly

I am trying to add multiple poly lines onto a map using mkmapkit. These poly lines indicate walking zones in my area. The problem is that my code is too bulky for a large amount of walking zones.

At the moment my code only indicates 2 walking routes but for instance if I want to add 100 or 1000 walking routes the code would be massive. I'm sure there is a way I could stream line this code so I could add in multiple walking zones with a lot less code but in not too sure the best way to go about it.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?

init(pinTitle:String, pinSubTitle:String, location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = pinTitle
    self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
    self.coordinate = location
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //co-ordinates
    let zone1S = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.100525, longitude: -9.623071)
    let zone1E = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.07241, longitude: -9.575299)

    let zone2S = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.054161, longitude: -9.385031)
    let zone2E = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.081185, longitude: -9.247033)


    //pins
    let zone1PinS = customPin(pinTitle: "Zone 1 Start", pinSubTitle: "", location: zone1S)
    let zone1PinE = customPin(pinTitle: "Zone 1 End", pinSubTitle: "", location: zone1E)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(zone1PinS)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(zone1PinE)

    let zone2PinS = customPin(pinTitle: "Zone 2 Start", pinSubTitle: "", location: zone2S)
    let zone2PinE = customPin(pinTitle: "Zone 2 End", pinSubTitle: "", location: zone2E)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(zone2PinS)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(zone2PinE)


    let zone1PlacemarkS = MKPlacemark(coordinate: zone1S)
    let zone1PlacemarkE = MKPlacemark(coordinate: zone1E)

    let zone2PlacemarkS = MKPlacemark(coordinate: zone2S)
    let zone2PlacemarkE = MKPlacemark(coordinate: zone2E)


    //add polyline to map
    let directionRequestZone1 = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequestZone1.source = MKMapItem(placemark: zone1PlacemarkS)
    directionRequestZone1.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: zone1PlacemarkE)

    let directionRequestZone2 = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequestZone2.source = MKMapItem(placemark: zone2PlacemarkS)
    directionRequestZone2.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: zone2PlacemarkE)


    //type of commute
    directionRequestZone1.transportType = .automobile
     directionRequestZone2.transportType = .automobile


    let directions1 = MKDirections(request: directionRequestZone1)
    directions1.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let directionResonse = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("we have error getting directions==\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }

        let route = directionResonse.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)


        let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        //zooming in on location
       // self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
    }


    let directions2 = MKDirections(request: directionRequestZone2)
    directions2.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let directionResonse = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("we have error getting directions==\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }

        let route2 = directionResonse.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay(route2.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)


        let rect = route2.polyline.boundingMapRect
        //zooming in on location
       // self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rect), animated: true)
    }


    //set delegate for mapview
    self.mapView.delegate = self
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0
    return renderer
}
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: coordinate]

UPDATE:
My attempt to use loops hasn't worked. I seem to have a loop working for dropping the start and end zone pins however it doesn't seem to work for drawing the poly lines.

```
        struct Location {
        let title: String
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double
    }

    let locationsStart = [
        Location(title: "Start",    latitude: 52.100525, longitude: -9.623071)
    ]

    let locationsEnd = [
        Location(title: "End",    latitude: 52.07241, longitude: -9.575299)
    ]

    for location in locationsStart {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location.title
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        let directionRequestZone1 = MKDirections.Request()
        let zonePlacemarkS = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: zonePlacemarkS)
        directionRequestZone1.transportType = .automobile
    }

    for location in locationsEnd {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location.title
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

        let directionRequestZone1 = MKDirections.Request()
        let zonePlacemarkE = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: zonePlacemarkE)
        directionRequestZone1.transportType = .automobile

        let directions1 = MKDirections(request: directionRequestZone1)
        directions1.calculate { (response, error) in
            guard let directionResonse = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("we have error getting directions==\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }

            let route = directionResonse.routes[0]
            self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)


            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        }
    }
           //set delegate for mapview
           self.mapView.delegate = self
}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0
    return renderer
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a loop is?

Comment: @matt yes I’ve had a play with trying to get them to work in this case but I couldn’t get it to work, so decided to ask to see what was the best way to solve my problem because I’m not sure if loops were the best way.

Comment: The way to roll code up into a loop is to do what you are doing: first write it all out for just a couple of cases. Now think about what is the same and what is different for each repetition. What is different becomes what you loop over. What is the same becomes the body of the loop. In your case, what's different is the coordinates. Everything else is the same.

Comment: @matt I have attempted to try and use loops. I think i have the loops working for planting the pins but I dont seem to have it working for adding the poly line for some reason.

Comment: Well the problem right now is that you've got _two_ loops.

Comment: @matt will you help out with the code I’m struggling here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted your code as follows:

```
let zone1S = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.100525, longitude: -9.623071)
let zone1E = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.07241, longitude: -9.575299)
let zone2S = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.054161, longitude: -9.385031)
let zone2E = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.081185, longitude: -9.247033)

let zones = [(start:zone1S, end:zone1E), (start:zone2S, end:zone2E)]
for (i, zone) in zones.enumerated() {
    let pinS = customPin(pinTitle: "Zone \(i+1) Start", pinSubTitle: "", location: zone.start)
    let pinE = customPin(pinTitle: "Zone \(i+1) End", pinSubTitle: "", location: zone.end)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pinS)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pinE)
    let placeS = MKPlacemark(coordinate: zone.start)
    let placeE = MKPlacemark(coordinate: zone.end)
    let req = MKDirections.Request()
    req.source = MKMapItem(placemark: placeS)
    req.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: placeE)
    req.transportType = .automobile
    let dir = MKDirections(request: req)
    dir.calculate { (response, error) in
        guard let directionResponse = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("we have error getting directions==\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let route = directionResponse.routes[0]
            self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly this can be trivially extended to any number of zones. (It may be that we should be using something like a DispatchGroup to prevent the networking `calculate` calls from piling up too quickly, but the goal was to solve it for two pairs of coordinates and this seems to work fine.)

Comment: Thank you matt,  I understand what i should have done  to implement the loop. When i ran your code it actually didn't produce the poly lines, it just produces the pins. So your code was quite close.

Comment: Produced the lines on my machine, looks just like your screen shot

Comment: Naturally I only showed you the code I changed. Everything else is just as you had it.

Comment: your 100% right, fault on my end. cheer man i really appreciate it. i learned alot. thanks again.